# Using .loc with a MultiIndex in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Does anyone know if it is possible to use the `DataFrame.loc` method to select from a `MultiIndex`? I have the following `DataFrame` and would like to be able to access the values located in the `Dwell` columns, at the indices of `('at', 1)`, `('at', 3)`, `('at', 5)`, and so on (non-sequential).

I'd love to be able to do something like `data.loc[['at',[1,3,5]], 'Dwell']`, similar to the `data.loc[[1,3,5], 'Dwell']` syntax for a regular index (which returns a 3-member series of `Dwell` values).

My purpose is to select an arbitrary subset of the data, perform some analysis only on that subset, and then update the new values with the results of the analysis. I plan on using the same syntax to set new values for these data, so chaining selectors wouldn't really work in this case.

Here is a slice of the `DataFrame` I'm working with:

```
         Char    Dwell  Flight  ND_Offset  Offset
QGram                                                           
at    0     a      100     120   0.000000       0  
      1     t      180       0   0.108363       5  
      2     a      100     120   0.000000       0 
      3     t      180       0   0.108363       5 
      4     a       20     180   0.000000       0  
      5     t       80     120   0.108363       5
      6     a       20     180   0.000000       0   
      7     t       80     120   0.108363       5  
      8     a       20     180   0.000000       0  
      9     t       80     120   0.108363       5   
      10    a      120     180   0.000000       0
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

If you are on version 0.14, you can simply pass a tuple to `.loc` as below:

```
df.loc[('at', [1,3,4]), 'Dwell']
```

Comment: Funny because if instead of a tuple, you pass a list, it does not work properly

Comment: @leoschet Pandas interprets tuple entries as levels and list entries as items in a level. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index FYI

Answer (score 20):

Try the [cross-section](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#cross-section-with-hierarchical-index) indexing:

```
In [68]: df.xs('at', level='QGram', drop_level=False).loc[[1,4]]
Out[68]: 
        Char  Dwell  Flight  ND_Offset  Offset
QGram                                         
at    1    t    180       0   0.108363       5
      4    a     20     180   0.000000       0
```

Comment: This would be the way that the pandas docs recommend, as slicing with deep indexes can be done with xs: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-xs

Comment: Is `xs` still recommended?

Comment: @baxx. Yes, `xs` is still recommended. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/user_guide/advanced.html#cross-section

Answer (score 5):

[`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) method is your best friend with multi-index. However, you must understand how loc works on multi indexes. When using loc on multi indexes you must specify every other index value in the loc such as:

```
df.loc['indexValue1', 'indexValue2', 'indexValue3']
```

However, as you may imagine this may be a pain in cases you don't know what all the other values are so we can of course use ':'

```
df.loc[:, 'value1', 'value2', :]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This not work for pandas 0.24

Answer (score 3):

In general, MultiIndex keys take the form of **tuples**. For example:

```py
In [6]: df.loc[('at', 1),'Dwell']
Out[6]: 180
```

In your case, you would have to pass a **list of tuples**. For example, the following works as you would expect:

```py
In [7]: df.loc[ [('at', 1),('at', 3),('at', 5)], 'Dwell']
Out[7]:
          Dwell
QGram                                                           
at    1    180
at    3    180 
at    5     80
```

Comment: More info can be found here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html