# pandas: conditional select using .loc with MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have read doc of [Advanced indexing with hierarchical index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index) where using `.loc` for `MultiIndex` is explained. Also this thread: [Using .loc with a MultiIndex in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435788/using-loc-with-a-multiindex-in-pandas)

Still I don't see how select rows where `(first index == some value) or (second index == some value)`

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
                                  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']],
                                  names=['i0', 'i1'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'y': [6,5,4,3,2,1]}, index=index)
```

Is this DataFrame:

```
       x  y
i0 i1      
a  a   1  6
   b   2  5
   c   3  4
b  a   4  3
   b   5  2
   c   6  1
```

How can I get rows where `i0 == 'b' or i1 == 'b'`?

```
       x  y
i0 i1      
a  b   2  5
b  a   4  3
   b   5  2
   c   6  1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`get_level_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html)

```
>>> mask = (df.index.get_level_values(0)=='b') | (df.index.get_level_values(1)=='b') 
>>> df[mask]  # same as df.loc[mask]


        x   y
i0  i1      
a   b   2   5
b   a   4   3
    b   5   2
    c   6   1
```

Answer (score 10):

I think the easier answer is to use the [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) function which allows you to query the multi-index by name as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([list("aaabbb"),
                                  list("abcabc")],
                                  names=['i0', 'i1'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'y': [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]}, index=index)


df.query('i0 == "b" | i1 == "b"')
```

returns:

```
       x  y
i0 i1      
a  b   2  5
b  a   4  3
   b   5  2
   c   6  1
```

Answer (score 5):

This might be possible with some logical condition on the index columns `i0` and `i1` unsing `.loc`. However to me using `.iloc` seems easier:

You can get the `iloc` index via [`pd.MultiIndex.get_locs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.get_locs.html).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([list("aaabbb"),
                                  list("abcabc")],
                                  names=['i0', 'i1'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'y': [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]}, index=index)

idx0 = index.get_locs(['b', slice(None)])  # i0 == 'b' => [3, 4, 5]
idx1 = index.get_locs([slice(None), 'b'])  # i1 == 'b' => [1, 4]
idx = np.union1d(idx0, idx1)

print(df.iloc[idx])
```

will yield

```
       x  y
i0 i1      
a  b   2  5
b  a   4  3
   b   5  2
   c   6  1
```

Note:
`slice(None)` means the same as `[:]` in index-slicing.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite some time since this question was raised. After reading the answers available, however, I do see the benefit of adding my response which is going to answer original query exactly and how do it efficiently with minimum coding.

To select multiple indices as in your question, you can do :

df.loc[('b','b')]

Please note most critical point here is to use parenthesis () for indices. This will give an output :

x    5
y    2
Name: (b, b), dtype: int64

You can further add column name ('x' in my case) as if needed by doing as below:

df.loc[('b','b'),'x']

This will give output:
5

Entire process is in the attached image.

[image: How to access multiple indices in a multiindex dataframe]

Comment: Your answer  is correct if the question was how to get (i0 == 'b' AND i1 == 'b'), but the question was about (i0 == 'b' OR i1 == 'b'). In your example the correct code should have returned the second line (i0=a and i1=b) and the last three lines (where i0 is b)