# Pandas xs where level in list of options

Tags: pandas, multi-index

If I have a pd.DataFrame that looks like:

```
new_df = []
for i in range(10):
    df_example = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=[10,1]))
    cols = [round(np.random.uniform(low=0,high=10)),round(np.random.uniform(low=0,high=10)),
        round(np.random.uniform(low=0,high=10)),round(np.random.uniform(low=0,high=10))]
    keys = ['A','B','C','D']
    new_ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([cols],names=keys)
    df_example.columns = new_ix
    new_df.append(df_example)
new_df = pd.concat(new_df,axis=1)
```

Which could yield something like:
[image]

Now, if I want where `C=4` and `A=1` I can do:

```
df.xs(axis=1,level=['A','C'],key=[1,4])
```

How do I express if I want:

1. `C in [4,2]` and `A in [5,2]`
2. `C in [4,2]` or `A in [5,2]`

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, you can't use anything but tuples for key parameter in xs, so such queries are not possible.

The next best thing is to define helper functions for that purpose, such as the following:

```py
def xs_or(df: pd.DataFrame, params: dict[str, list[int]]) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Helper function.

    Args:
        df: input dataframe.
        params: columns/values to query.

    Returns:
        Filtered dataframe.

    """
    df = pd.concat(
        [
            df.xs(axis=1, level=[level], key=(key,))
            for level, keys in params.items()
            for key in keys
        ],
        axis=1,
    )
    for level in params.keys():
        try:
            df = df.droplevel([level], axis=1)
        except KeyError:
            pass
    return df


def xs_and(df: pd.DataFrame, params: dict[str, list[int]]) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Helper function.

    Args:
        df: input dataframe.
        params: columns/values to query.

    Returns:
        Filtered dataframe.

    """
    for level, keys in params.items():
        df = xs_or(df, {level: keys})
    return df
```

And so, with the following dataframe named `df`:

```py
A         4         7         3         1         7         9         4         0         3         9
B         6         7         4         6         7         5         8         0         8         0
C        2         10        5         2         9         9         4         3         4         5 
D        0         1         7         3         8         3         6         7         9         10
0 -0.199458  1.155345  1.298027  0.575606  0.785291 -1.126484  0.019082  1.765094  0.034631 -0.243635
1  1.173873  0.523277 -0.709546  1.378983  0.266661  1.626118  1.647584 -0.228162 -1.708271  0.111583
2  0.321156  0.049470 -0.611111 -1.238887  1.092369  0.019503 -0.473618  1.804474 -0.850320 -0.217921
3  0.339307 -0.758909  0.072159  1.636119 -0.541920 -0.160791 -1.131100  1.081766 -0.530082 -0.546489
4 -1.523110 -0.662232 -0.434115  1.698073  0.568690  0.836359 -0.833581  0.230585  0.166119  1.085600
5  0.020645 -1.379587 -0.608083 -1.455928  1.855402  1.714663 -0.739409  1.270043  1.650138 -0.718430
6  1.280583 -1.317288  0.899278 -0.032213 -0.347234  2.543415  0.272228 -0.664116 -1.404851 -0.517939
7 -1.201619  0.724669 -0.705984  0.533725  0.820124  0.651339  0.363214  0.727381 -0.282170  0.651201
8  1.829209  0.049628  0.655277 -0.237327 -0.007662  1.849530  0.095479  0.295623 -0.856162 -0.350407
9 -0.690613  1.419008 -0.791556  0.180751 -0.648182  0.240589 -0.247574 -1.947492 -1.010009  1.549234
```

You can filter like this:

```py
# C in [10, 2] or A in [1, 0]
print(xs_or(df, {"C": [10, 2], "A": [1, 0]}))
# Output
B         7         6                   2         3
D         1         0         3         3         7
0  1.155345 -0.199458  0.575606  0.575606  1.765094
1  0.523277  1.173873  1.378983  1.378983 -0.228162
2  0.049470  0.321156 -1.238887 -1.238887  1.804474
3 -0.758909  0.339307  1.636119  1.636119  1.081766
4 -0.662232 -1.523110  1.698073  1.698073  0.230585
5 -1.379587  0.020645 -1.455928 -1.455928  1.270043
6 -1.317288  1.280583 -0.032213 -0.032213 -0.664116
7  0.724669 -1.201619  0.533725  0.533725  0.727381
8  0.049628  1.829209 -0.237327 -0.237327  0.295623
9  1.419008 -0.690613  0.180751  0.180751 -1.947492
```

```py
# C in [10, 2] and A in [1, 7]
print(xs_and(df, {"C": [10, 2], "A": [1, 7]}))
# Output
B         6         7
D         3         1
0  0.575606  1.155345
1  1.378983  0.523277
2 -1.238887  0.049470
3  1.636119 -0.758909
4  1.698073 -0.662232
5 -1.455928 -1.379587
6 -0.032213 -1.317288
7  0.533725  0.724669
8 -0.237327  0.049628
9  0.180751  1.419008
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032985/pandas-conditional-select-using-loc-with-multiindex This answer seemed promising but haven’t tested.